# double for loop with ImageButtons?

Tags: android, for-loop, imagebutton

Hey guys so I'm doing this double for loop. So in the first for loop, im looping through a couple imageButtons. The second for loop im looping through string values (strings such as "food", "bar", "sports"). What I want to be able to do is set the first imageButton to a food icon if the second array's first element is the word "food" and the second imagebutton to a picture of a cocktail if the second word of the second array is "bar". Here is what I got. What it currently does is set all the imageButtons to a "food icon".

```
    for(ImageButton button : iconArray)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < tags.size(); i ++)
        {
            if(tags.get(i) == "food")
            {
                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.small_icon_food);
                break;
            }
            else if(tags.get(i) == "bar")
            {
                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.small_icon_bar);
                break;
            }

              etc..


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is unreasonable, it will make your button always use last tags. Please correct like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < iconArray.length; i ++)
{
    ImageButton button = iconArray[i];
    if(tags.get(i) == "food")
    {
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.small_icon_food);
        break;
    }
    else if(tags.get(i) == "bar")
    {
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.small_icon_bar);
        break;
    }

      etc..

}
```

Comment: Sorry was having a coding brain fart.. Thanks for the solution man.